# How to get the different elements of two arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have two arrays of integers . suppose A[5] = {1,2,3,4,5} and B[6] = [1,2,3,6,7,8]  .Now If some elements is present in A But not is B , i want to remove that element from A . But if some element is present in B But not in A , I want to add that element in A.If elements are there in both Arrays,then leave them as it is. that How can i efficiently achieve this.

For the example above the final output will be :-

A[] = {1,2,3,6,7,8} or we can save the output in separate Array as well.
C[] = {1,2,3,6,7,8}

Comment: Why not create a hash-tables for the elements in A and B?

Comment: @JohnColeman can you elaborate a bit plz

Comment: @PardeepKr you know hashing right?

Comment: If the arrays are sorted, then you can do a simple merge. If they're not sorted, you either need to sort them first or use extra memory to create a hash map. Also, your solution will depend on whether duplicates are allowed in either list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. If some elements is present in A But not is B , i want to remove that element from A
> 2. But if some element is present in B But not in A , I want to add that element in A.
> 3. If elements are there in both Arrays,then leave them as it is.

So, every element from B should be in result, and no element that isn't in B shouldn't be in result.

> How can i efficiently achieve this.

I think, you can just reset A and copy elements of B to it.

Comment: dang that's clever! and not I think about it, his `C` is identical to `B`

Comment: Good answer (+1), but there are possible questions about the multiplicity of the elements, as well as their ordering, that this answer doesn't address. For example -- if `1` is in `A` 3 times and in `B` just once, shouldn't it be in the answer 3 times?

Comment: I have a suspicion that such details bother asker in the least)

Comment: @aaalex88 The order doest not matter and every element occurs once 
nice simple answer . thanks.